# How can I make a GET method working in tomcat servlet?

Tags: html, tomcat, web, servlets, server

Here's my simple code which is a web form that collects some information. I tried to use `GET` method, but it keeps `POST` method working even though I specified it on the 8th line.
Am I missing something?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>My Form</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form action="/mSignUp" method="get">
      name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
      hobby: sports <input type="checkbox" name="hobby" value="sports">
            cooking <input type="checkbox" name="hobby" value="cooking">
            reading <input type="checkbox" name="hobby" value="reading"><br><br>
      <input type="submit" value="submit">
    </form>

  </body>
</html>
```

**Servlet code:**

```
package com;


@WebServlet("/mSignUp")
public class ServletEX extends HttpServlet {

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        System.out.println(" -- doGet() -- ");
         ...

        }

    }

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        System.out.println(" -- doPost() -- ");
        doGet(request, response);
    }
}
```

Comment: How did you know that only post method was working?

Comment: not only was Post method working but also Get method was working. because I call doGet method in the doPost method. but I wanted only Get method working...

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want the Servlet to support POST, don't implement `doPost()`.